# How to import Fuse.js as ES6 module client side?

Tags: javascript, es6-modules, fuse.js

I use ES6 modules in my code but I cannot import Fuse on the client. In node, everything works, but in the browser (Firefox developer edition 66.0b4 on Linux), this fails (the code is in the `./js` folder):

```
import Fuse from "../node_modules/fuse.js/dist/fuse.js";
...
new Fuse(items,options);
```

The error is "SyntaxError: import not found: default". Can this be fixed or is it impossible to use Fuse as an ES6 module in the browser?

My package.json contains the dependency `"fuse.js": "^3.3.0"`. I don't use transpilation at this time.

P.S.: It works with the transpiled code, but I develop without transpilation.

Comment: import * as Fuse from fuse.js

Comment: @a2441918: Doesn't work for me.  `TypeError: Fuse is not a constructor` (Fuse.Fuse has the same problem). What is your setup?

Comment: why not `import Fuse from 'fuse.js'`

Comment: @AlexShtromberg: It won't find it like that in the browser. I want my code to function in all three environments: delevopment (browser, untranspiled), production (browser, transpiled) and testing (npm).

Comment: You have to transpile for the browser to understand `import` regardless whether you're in dev or prod mode.